# Compare two cells, if equal then delete and replace

Tags: vba, excel

I send data from one workbook to another. My macro copies and pastes the data into a masterdata document that stores all my data. After pasting the macro goes back and sets all my values to 0 before save then closing.

```
sub send()

Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\BB"
Worksheets("CC").Activate

Workbooks("AA").Activate

Worksheets("AA").Range("A3:F19").Copy

Workbooks("BB").Activate

ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("CC").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Workbooks("AA").Activate

Range("C3:E19").Value = 0

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

I need code to check if the date in the last row of column F in my masterdata workbook equals the date right now in month and year.

If it is equal, delete all with this date and replace with new data.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the datediff function like :

```
 ' Index run through a column
 For Index = 3 To 19
      If DateDiff(Now, ActiveSheet.Cells(Index, 5)) = 0 Then
         ' Replace here your new data
      End If
 Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll delete my "first answer", but here is my real answer to test:

```
Sub Send() 'asuming that this Sub is located in the "OriData"-Workbook
    Dim OriData As Workbook
    Set OriData = ThisWorkbook

    Dim MasterData As Workbook
    Set MasterData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\BB")

    Dim ODSht As Worksheet
    ODSht = OriData.Sheets("AA")


    Dim MDSht As Worksheet
    MDSht = MasterData.Sheets("CC")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = MDSht.Cells(MDSht.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row  'Last Row in Masterdata which contains data in Column a

    Dim NewDate As Date
    NewDate = MDSht.Cells(LastRow, 6)   'Last row, column F

    If month(Date) = month(NewDate.Value) And Year(Date) = Year(NewDate.Value) Then
```

Maybe you'll have to delete the .Value after NewDate (You'll have to try).

As I am not sure what exactly you want to delete, I'll write the code that the whole row in masterdata gets deleted where in column F the date (month and year) is corresponding to the date of "today":

```
        MDSht.Row(LastRow).Delete
```

If you want to delete more than just one line, you will have to change the code accordingly but maybe this will help you a little.

```
    End If

    MasterData.Save
    MasterData.Close
```

Why in your code is the Range you're copying (A3:F19) and the Range you're setting to 0 (C3:E19) not the same??

```
    OriData.Activate
    ODSht.Range("A3:F19").Value = 0

    OriData.Save
    OriData.Close
End Sub
```

If you would make a function out of LastRow and NewDate you could loop it with new Data to control each time without further complications:

```
Function LastRow(WS As Worksheet)
    LastRow = WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End Function

Function NewDate(Sht As Worksheet, R As Long)
    NewDate = Sht.Cells(R, 6).Value
End Function
```

Following the If-Condition from before:

```
For DRow = 1 To LastRow(MDSht)
    If (month(Date) = month(NewDate(MDSht, DRow))) And (Year(Date) = Year(NewDate(MDSht, DRow))) Then
        MDSht.Row(DRow).Delete
    ElseIf DRow = LastRow(MDSht)
        MsgBox "Finished", vbokOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next DRow
```

Tell me, if it worked and what did not (is interesting for me to know, and I can learn more from it), thank you :)